# In Play Framework, is there a simple way to de/serialize instances according to JSON API (jsonapi.org)?

Tags: playframework, json-api

With Play 2.4 (Java), is there a simple way using existing Play JSON or Play plugins to de/serialize instances according to [jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org)? We are writing our own de/serializers, basing on Jackson, to communicate with our Ember.js frontend. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Play JSON to do de/serialize objects. Refer https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

Jackson also a library to do de/serialize the instances.

In both cases you have to write code to do the job. There is no library of components in Play which does auto conversions

Comment: OP asks about Java, not Scala.

Comment: I am ok with Scala solution if there is one. I know about Play JSON but I have to fiddle JSON just like Jackson which what we are working on now.

Comment: Okay,  here is Java one. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJsonActions. I meant you have to your own parsers there is nothing which does automatically.